# Add Z value to an existing 2D point in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm facing this query which is used to extract a centroid point (3D) of a 3D polygon resulting from the cartographic intersection of a 2D polygon given by the user of an application (which is inserted dynamically and is represented by the raw `MULTIPOLYGON` string hereunder) and some large 3D polygons (actually `MULTIPOLYGON ZM`) stored in an existing PostGIS table named `polygon_table`:

```
SELECT 
st_setsrid(
  st_makepoint(
    st_x(
      st_centroid(
        st_intersection(
          polygon_table.geom,
          ST_Transform(
            ST_GeomFromText(
              'MULTIPOLYGON(((
                 8.0118 46.5232,
                 7.9930 46.5476,
                 7.9935 46.5476,
                 8.0118 46.5232)))',
            4326),
          2056)))),
    st_y(
      st_centroid(
        st_intersection(
          polygon_table.geom,
          ST_Transform(
            ST_GeomFromText(
              'MULTIPOLYGON(((
                 8.0118 46.5232,
                 7.9930 46.5476,
                 7.9935 46.5476,
                 8.0118 46.5232)))',
            4326),
          2056)))),
    (
     st_zmax(
       st_intersection(
         polygon_table.geom,
         ST_Transform(
            ST_GeomFromText(
              'MULTIPOLYGON(((
                 8.0118 46.5232,
                 7.9930 46.5476,
                 7.9935 46.5476,
                 8.0118 46.5232)))',
            4326),
          2056))) +
     st_zmin(
       st_intersection(
         polygon_table.geom,
         ST_Transform(
            ST_GeomFromText(
              'MULTIPOLYGON(((
                 8.0118 46.5232,
                 7.9930 46.5476,
                 7.9935 46.5476,
                 8.0118 46.5232)))',
            4326),
          2056)))
    )/2),
  2056)
FROM polygon_table
WHERE id = 1
;
```

Because the polygon given by the user can have >>> hundreds of thousands vertices (I over-simplified this polygon here), I would like to simplify this query to limit the number of `ST_Intersection()` calls, e.g. by not extracting both the X and Y coordinates to build the point using `ST_MakePoint()`, but if possible by only *appending* the computed mean Z-value of the resulting 3D polygon intersection to the point given by `ST_Centroid()`.

Is this possible? Or does it exist a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a sub-query for the `ST_Intersection` used in deriving the `Z` value, and a `LATERAL` for the extra call to `ST_Ceontroid`:

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(
         ST_X(ctr),
         ST_Y(ctr),
         (ST_ZMin(its.geom)+ST_ZMax(its.geom)) / 2.0
      ) AS geom
FROM   (
  SELECT ST_Intersection(pt.geom, <dynamic_polygon>) AS geom
  FROM   polygon_table AS pt
  WHERE  id = 1
  --AND  ST_Intersects(pt.geom, <dynamic_polygon>)
) AS its, LATERAL ST_Centroid(its.geom) AS ctr
;
```

---

However, given that you pass in **2D geometries**, the `Z` value will always be `0.0`, so no need to calculate it, really:

```
SELECT ST_MakePoint(
         ST_X(ctr),
         ST_Y(ctr),
         0.0
      ) AS geom
FROM   (
  SELECT ST_Intersection(pt.geom, <dynamic_polygon>) AS geom
  FROM   polygon_table AS pt
  WHERE  id = 1
  --AND  ST_Intersects(pt.geom, <dynamic_polygon>)
) AS its
;
```

Not even *SFCGAL* backed `ST_3DIntersection` can do sth. about that.